# error coupled with custom form control component

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular-material-6

I'm trying to create a custom MatFormFieldControl which also implements the ControlValueAccessor.

I wanted to start with a known use case: password form.

The Plan: to create a form field that gets a single string, but have it's own form inside it that adds a validation against the confirmPassword field.

I created a [StackBlitz with a working implementation](https://stackblitz.com/edit/custom-inner-error?file=app%2Fpass%2Fpass.component.ts).

Every time the errorState variable is called, I check if there's a missmatch between the two fields, and update the errors on the ngControl so it can be reflected to the outside.

The error state is shown correctly at first, but if you match the passwords and than missmatch them again, this error is thrown:

```
Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'ngIf: null'. Current value: 'ngIf: [object Object]'.
```

I couldn't find a lot of documentation about this online and I'm not sure when is the right place to add the error to the errors object

Anyone known how I can avoid this error?

thanks in advance

```
get errorState() {
  const missmatch = this.weightForm.value.password !== this.weightForm.value.confirmPassword;

  if (missmatch) {
    this.ngControl.control.setErrors({ missmatch }, { emitEvent: false });
  }

  return (this.ngControl.errors !== null || missmatch) && !!this.ngControl.touched;
}
```

The idea here is to create a "separation of concerns" were the outer form doesn't know about confirmPassword since it's more of a "Validation" field instead of a "data" field if that makes sense.

Another example for this separation of concerns is to have a code editor as a form field and having the code editor validations reflect to the outside without exposing the code editor itself to the outside.

Answer (score 1):

testing your StackBlitz example i've seen that removing the *ngIf in app.component on the mat-error solve the problem keeping unchanged 
the "error reporting function" of form input, i don't know if this can solve your problem in your real site, but i think is worth a try.

But what i really suggest you for this kind of work (password match verification) is to rely on **Angular form validators** (here form documentation: https://angular.io/guide/form-validation) this approach is safer because you don't need to force the error checking via variables but is the form that alone understand if a field is invalid.

There is no standard validators for check if 2 fields contain the same text but you can build your custom validator that do what you want.

If this can be helpful i'll share the syntax of the custom validator that i usually use for password check (only as a trace, for sure you must modify something to make it work):

```
export function mismatchValidator(): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} | null => {
        if (control.parent) {
            if (control.parent.get('password').value !== control.parent.get('password_confirmation').value) {
                return {mismatch: true};
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    };
}
```

Other informations about how to implement form controller, validators and custom validators can be found on Angular site.

Here's an interesting [article](https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4) about your issue, maybe it can be useful to help you to understand where your problem is if you choose to not implement form Validators.

Comment: I was about to write a validator for the inner formGroup, but wanted to make sure it's worth while.

The reason I'm doing it like that is since the confirmPassword isn't actually part of the outside form. I don't want the outer form to know about confirm password since it's not a "field" as much as it is part of the validation itself.
So basically I'm trying to "transform" an inner validator to an outside form that isn't aware of the inner fields

I'll try your suggestion later today. thanks!

Comment: Well, maybe you can use the inner form controller for validation since the father and child form controller are independent , then you can propagate with @output directive the status of the form of child to father component and trigger the error.
Your problem is that the value of your variable is changed during the change detection cycle, maybe this can prevent the error.

Comment: your solution doesn't work since I still need to update the outside validation from the inside validation and I get the same error. The idea here is that I want to transfer the validation and I need to find the right time to do this. The article you sent is relevant, but because I can't control when the errorState function is called, I can't "update it on the next cycle"

Comment: the custom validator can't be set from outside since the outside shouldn't know about the inner `confirmPassword` field in this implementation. The idea here is to create a "separation of concerns" were the outer form doesn't know about `confirmPassword` since it's more of a "Validation" field instead of a "data" field if that makes sense

Comment: The problem is that you try to update parent inside the child component during Angular check cycle, but the 2 formGroup are already separated so are the form "concerns".
The validator can help you to validate the single form, but it cant solve the error, because the error isn't related to a validation problem.
I think that for avoid this error the child must not update parent values, but only notify that the inner form have an error, then the parent will take care to print the correct message in the outer form.

Comment: That's right. I'm not trying to solve a validation error. I'm trying to solve exactly the problem you described in your last comment. All I'm saying is that your answer didn't solve my problem, and I think this is solvable. I less need help with understanding what's the problem here and more trying to find a solution while keeping the original idea of the code (to have an inner validation). that's why I'm not marking it as the answer.

Comment: ok i got your point, you're right mine is not the correct answer, but i don't know if your problem is solvable without changing (at least a little) the logic with which you update parent form. 
I've faced this problem before, and all the times i had to change something in my logics, because the error is explicitly telling me that i'm trying to implement a bad practice.
For solve your problem you may try [this](https://medium.com/@joshblf/dynamic-nested-reactive-forms-in-angular-654c1d4a769a) the idea is keeping the validation of the forms in a external service, and use it in both forms

Comment: I'm trying to not expose the inner validation, just its results. Also, the form control looks different from inside and outside. About the article: The outer form sees a single value while the inner form sees two values. so sharing the validator is only possible if the form is the same. I'm trying to avoid making the outer form aware of `confirmPassword`. If that concept is kept, it will solve my problem. The articles you suggest are great on their own, but are not relevant to this question :-) Look at the example I addedwith a code editor. it might explain the problem better

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a bit late in the day, but I stumbled on this question while researching another issue and thought it would be worth adding an answer to help anyone else who reads this.

The issue is the way the error is being set inside the getter. At some point Angular will be reading the value of the property while inside a change detection loop, if you change the control errors at this point you will get the Expression Changed error.

The easy fix is to change slightly the way you are testing and setting the errors. In your stackblitz I changed the error state back to a boolean field and added the validation check to the DoCheck lifecycle hook.

```
  ngDoCheck() {
    const missmatch = this.innerForm.value.password !== this.innerForm.value.confirmPassword;

    if (missmatch) {
      this.ngControl.control.setErrors({ missmatch });
      this.errorState = true;
      return;
    }

    this.errorState = false;
  }
```

[Modified stackblitz with the fix](https://stackblitz.com/edit/custom-inner-error-9rtp3z?file=app%2Fpass%2Fpass.component.ts)